# I want to know some methods for connecting Netsuite SavedSearches to SSIS?

Tags: ssis, netsuite, sql-server-data-tools

I am trying  to create an ETL in SQL Server Integration Services 2014 .I want to connect the NetSuite SavedSearches which will act as source for the ETL. I got one method which is exporting the SavedSearch to the CSV file but is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: If you can use .NET to retrieve a saved search, you can use a Script Source.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the SuiteTalk SOAP API to run a saved search. [Here's an example](https://github.com/netsweet/netsuite#searching) using the NetSuite ruby gem.